# Constraint to see if one type "satisfies" another

Tags: haskell, type-constraints

Is there a way to write a constraint:

```
C t1 t2 :: Constraint
```

Such that it "satisfies" (is that the right word) if `t2` matches against `t1`.

For example:

```
C (forall a. Num a => a -> a -> a) (forall a. Num a => a -> a -> a) -- good
C (forall a. Num a => a -> a -> a) (Int -> Int -> Int) -- good
C (forall a. Num a => a -> a -> a) (Bool -> Bool -> Bool) -- fails
C (Int -> Int -> Int) (forall a. Num a => a -> a -> a) -- fails
```

Comment: I think you may be interested in [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.9/docs/Data-Constraint-Forall.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic answer is no. Haskell's type system is *predicative*: a type variable can only be instantiated to a monotype. So if you had

```
class C t u
```

or

```
type family C t u
```

the `t` and `u` simply *can't* be instantiated to the polymorphic types you want to talk about.